# Change non-editor colors in RubyMine to looks like Idea

Tags: color-theme

How can i change panels and tool windows fill color?

I want my rubymine -- [image] looks like new sexy InteliJ Idea -- [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's solved in RubyMine (Enoki) RM-125.9 (EAP)